# Adding and subtracting two's complement

Tags: binary, twos-complement

Using six-bit one's and two's complement representation I am trying to solve the following problem:

```
12 - 7
```

Now, i take 12 in binary and 7 in binary first.

```
12 = 001100 - 6 bit 
7 =  000111 - 6 bit
```

Then, would I then flip the bit for two's complement and add one?

```
12 = 110011 ones complement 
     +    1
    -------
     001101

7  = 111000 ones complement 
    +     1
   ---------
      111001
```

then, add those two complement together

```
 001101
+111001
-------
1000110 = overflow? discard the last digit?  If so I get 5
```

Now, if I have a number like

```
-15 + 2
```

I would then add a sign magnitude on the MSB if it's a zero?

like:

```
-15 = 001111 6 bit
```

Would I add a 1 at the end here before I flip the bits?

```
  = 101111
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using two's complement to represent negative values has the benefit that subtraction and addition are the same. In your case, you can think of `12 - 7` as `12 + (-7)`. Hence you only need to find the two's complement representation of -7 and add it to +12:

```
12  001100
-7  111001   -- to get this, invert all bits of 7 (000111) and add 1
----------
 5 1000101
```

Then discard the carry (indicates overflow), and you have your result: `000101` which equals to 5 as expected.

For your example of `-15 + 2`, simply follow the same procedure to get the two's complement representation of -15:

```
15  001111
    110000   -- inverted bits
    110001   -- add 1
```

Now do the addition as usual:

```
-15  110001
  2  000010
-----------
res  110011
```

To see that `res` indeed equals -13, you can see that it is negative (MSB set). For the magnitude, convert to positive (invert bits, add 1):

```
res  110011
     001100  -- inverted bits
     001101  -- add 1
```

Hence the magnitude is 13 as expected.

Comment: Why would i only need to find the two's complement representation of -7 and add it to +12:???? how do i know when to use twos compliment then? thank you BTW

Comment: Two's complement (and one's complement for that matter) are means to represent negative numbers. Since +12 is not a negative number, you can use it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

No. The algorithm for two's complement doesn't change based on where the negative value is.