# Overflow in bitwise subtraction using two's complement

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

When performing bitwise subtraction using two's complement, how does one know when the overflow should be ignored? Several websites I read stated that the overflow is simply ignored, but that does not always work -- the overflow is necessary for problems like `-35 - 37`, as an extra digit is needed to express the answer of `-72`.

EDIT: Here's an example, using the above equation.

`35` to binary -> `100011`, find two's complement to make it negative: `011101`

`37` to binary -> `100101`, find two's complement to make it negative: `011011`

Perform addition of above terms (binary equivalent of `-35 - 37`):

```
011101
011011
------
111000
```

Take two's complement to convert back to positive: `001000`

The above is what many websites (including academic ones) say the answer should be, as you ignore overflow. This is clearly incorrect, however.

Comment: Clearly those websites aren't describing how to compute `-32 - 37` bitwise then :-)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3878135/1672458) states it, as well as step 4 on [this academic webpage](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~csonline/NumberSystems/Lessons/SubtractionWithTwosComplement/index.html). [This PowerPoint](http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.uiuc.edu%2Fclass%2Fsp08%2Fcs231%2Flectures%2F10-Subtraction.pdf) (Google Viewer link) also shows it on slide 9.

Comment: What is bitwise subtraction? do you mean subtraction in 2's complement? If that is the case, then your question should be, when is there an overflow in 2's complement addition of negative integers of width `N` (for example)?

Comment: Can you explain your expectation of "bitwise" subtraction?  Does this differ from subtraction?  (You are using the - operator, so I don't know what you mean by bitwise?)  Also, I didn't see any overflow in your example?  You might check here http://www.hackersdelight.org/ for some handy overflow detection algorithms.  Also, depending on your hardware, there is sometimes a register bit set when overflow occurs (however this is only after it has occurred).

Comment: Just added an example using `-35 - 37` to the main post, does that help?

Comment: @StevenH it helps a little. The problem with the your numbers as related to the bits you're using (6 bits) is it violates the signed-number requirement of the standard. By C99-§6.2.6.2,2, one of the bits of your signed number *must* be preserved to denote sign-state. Further, the same section states that excluding the sign-bit, the remaining bits representation must correspond to an associated unsigned type of the remaining bit-count. The number of bits you've chosen and the values you're attempting to represent within those bits violate that portion of the standard. Hate when that happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An overflow happens when the result cannot be represented in the target data type.  The value -72 can be represented in a char, which is a signed 8-bit quantity... there is no overflow in your example.  Perhaps you are thinking about a `borrow` while doing bitwise subtraction... when you subtract a `'1'` from a `'0'` you need to `borrow` from the next higher order bit position.  You cannot ignore borrows when doing subtraction.

```
-35 decimal is   11011101 in two's complement 8-bit
+37 decimal is   00100101 in two's complement 8-bit
```

going right to left from least significant to most significant bit you can subtract each bit in +37 from each bit in -35 until you get to bit 5 (counting starts at bit 0 on the right).  At bit position 5 you need to subtract `'1'` from `'0'` so you need to borrow from bit position 6 (the next higher order bit) in -35, which happens to be a `'1'` prior to the borrow.  The result looks like this

```
-35 decimal is   11011101 in two's complement 8-bit
+37 decimal is   00100101 in two's complement 8-bit
                 --------
-72 decimal is   10111000 in two's complement 8-bit
```

The result is negative, and your result in 8-bit two's complement has the high order bit set (bit 7)... which is negative, so there is no overflow.

**Update**:I think I see where the confusion is, and I claim that the answer here [Adding and subtracting two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878062/adding-and-subtracting-twos-complement/) is wrong when it says you can `discard the carry (indicates overflow)`.  In that answer they do subtraction by converting the second operand to negative using two's complement and then adding.  That's fine - but a carry doesn't represent overflow in that case.  If you add two positive numbers in N bits (numbered 0 to N-1) and you consider this unsigned arithmetic `range 0 to (2^N)-1` and you get a carry out of bit position N-1 then you have overflow - the sum of two positive numbers (interpreted as unsigned to maximize the range of representable positive numbers) should not generate a carry out of the highest order bit (bit N-1).  So when adding two positive numbers you identify overflow by saying

1. there must be no carry out of bit N-1 when you interpret them as unsigned and
2. the result in bit N-1 must be zero when interpreted as signed (two's complement)

Note, however, that processors don't distinguish between signed and unsigned addition/subtraction... they set the overflow flag to indicate that **if** you are interpreting your data as signed **then** the result could not be represented (is wrong).

Here is [a very detailed explanation of carry and overflow flag](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt). The takeaway from that article is this

- In `unsigned` arithmetic, watch the carry flag to detect errors.
- In `unsigned` arithmetic, the overflow flag tells you nothing interesting.
- In `signed` arithmetic, watch the overflow flag to detect errors.
- In `signed` arithmetic, the carry flag tells you nothing interesting.

This is consistent with the [definition of arithmetic overflow in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow) which says

> Most computers distinguish between two kinds of overflow conditions. A carry occurs when     the result of an addition or subtraction, considering the operands and result as unsigned numbers, does not fit in the result. Therefore, it is useful to check the carry flag after adding or subtracting numbers that are interpreted as unsigned values. An overflow proper occurs when the result does not have the sign that one would predict from the signs of the operands (e.g. a negative result when adding two positive numbers). Therefore, it is useful to check the overflow flag after adding or subtracting numbers that are represented in two's complement form (i.e. they are considered signed numbers).

Comment: The original question was spurred by a homework problem requiring 6-bit numbers, thus the way my (just-added) example is written. So many websites (see my first comment on the main post) say to simply ignore overflow, but that's not the case.

Comment: Ok, that changes things... if you are restricted to 6-bit numbers then  you have a problem representing both -35 and +37, both of those require 7-bit two's complement to represent.  In two's complement the range for a 6-bit number is -32 to +31 (100000 binary to 011111 binary).

Comment: As noted in a comment I left to the question, attempting to represent a signed integer in a bit-depth that does not account for reservation of the sign-bit is not allows, which I *think* is the fundamental issue with the question values as presented. So I believe this answer is accurate.

Comment: Ah, the updated version makes perfect sense. (Well, the original version did, but this one is better. :) ) Thank you so much!